# I can't install apk from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, apk

I've installed eclipse in a new computer with windows 8, I've copy the workspace from my old PC and now I can open the projects and work with them normally, but when I try to install the apk in a device or in the emulator, appears an error in the console:

*Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!*

This is the logcat:

```
> 05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/J i A.apk
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:649)
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644):  at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:144)
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644):  at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:102)
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/PackageParser(3644):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-30 13:11:54.054: W/DefContainer(3644): Failed to parse package
05-30 13:11:54.062: I/ApplicationPolicy(187): isApplicationInstallationEnabled
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageManager(187): verifying app can be installed or not
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/J i A.apk
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:649)
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644):  at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:144)
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644):  at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:102)
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/PackageParser(3644):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/DefContainer(3644): Failed to parse package
05-30 13:11:54.062: W/ActivityManager(187): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/J i A.apk
```

If I try to export the application to generate the apk file, appears a dialog that says "Failed to export application".

Any idea to solve this? I can't test my app or generate the apk in anyway.

Comment: Try creating a new project and if that doesn't work try a fresh download of the ADT (Android Development Tools) and install again.

Comment: clean the project .... and rebuilt ... i too faced this issues ..

Comment: I've reinstalled eclipse, adt & sdk, and I cleaned the project and rebuilt, but the problems still exist. I'll try with a new project.

Comment: how did you inmport the project? With the import option, or by usin new->project->existing project into workspace? As far as I know the second option works most of the times

Comment: @rmooney It seems that with a new project the problem doesn't exists, but how can I install the existing projects in my workspace?

Comment: @Analizer I copied the workspace folder in my new computer, and when eclipse asked for the workspace, I selected this folder.

Comment: try to create the new project and run it.. if its running repace the xml and properties file in your project and check it

Comment: try to create a new project in a new workspace using your project as existing source

Comment: @Analizer do you mean importing the project with the option "Existing Android Code Into Workspace"?  It doesn't work. The problem goes on.

Comment: @Analizer I've created a new project and I've copy/paste all the files and folders from one of the project that doesn't work, and now the problem have disappeared, but this is not feasible to do that with all the projects... with this information, any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: @Sandy09 I've found one solution, but not good at all. You can read the solution in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the target SDK for the android app and make sure you have that SDK version installed.  You can change it in project properties.

Comment: I've checked it and this is not the solution